# Table csvreader with eleven columns

Tags: tables, csvsimple

The `\csvreader` to build a table without a header with eleven columns does not seem to work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
0.1,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.2,2.5,2.8,3.1,3.4
0.2,1.0,1.8,2.6,3.4,4.2,5.0,5.8,6.6,7.4,8.2,9.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
    \hline
    \csvreader[no head,table head=\hline,late after line=\\\hline]{data.csv}{1=\one,2=\two,3=\three,4=\four,5=\five,6=\six,7=\seven,8=\eight,9=\nine,10=\ten,11=\eleven}
    {\thecsvrow & \one & \two & \three & \four & \five & \six & \seven & \eight & \nine & \ten & \ten & \eleven}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Raises the following error:

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/csv head/11', to which you passed '\eleven ', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ... & \eight & \nine & \ten & \ten & \eleven}`

Taking out the eleventh column from the csvreader solves the problem, but is there a solution or a workaround to obtain eleven columns or more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `csvsimple` package assumes at most ten columns, by default, but the number is adjustable by setting the `column count` key.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
0.1,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.2,2.5,2.8,3.1,3.4
0.2,1.0,1.8,2.6,3.4,4.2,5.0,5.8,6.6,7.4,8.2,9.0
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
\hline
\csvreader[
  column count=11,
  no head,
  table head=\hline,
  late after line=\\\hline
]{\jobname.csv}{
  1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four,
  5=\five, 6=\six, 7=\seven, 8=\eight,
  9=\nine, 10=\ten, 11=\eleven
}
{\thecsvrow & \one & \two & \three & \four & \five & \six & \seven & \eight & \nine & \ten & \eleven}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]